# What is the correct notation and the correct solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

> My Question is,
>
> Which one is a correct notation and a correct solution?

$$2x+2 \mod (x^2-x-2)=2x+2$$

Or, $$\text{RemainderPolynomial} [2x+2,x^2-x-2,x]=2x+2$$

If, both are correct why the remainder must equal to $2x+2$ ?
Must we accept $x≥5$? Because, for only $x≥5$ we have, $2x+2<x^2-x-2$. Isn't it? I have a trouble the understand this.

Comment: Both variants are correct. The remainder is just the polynomial itself because its degree is less than the degree of the other polynomial. The values for some $x$ do not matter.

Comment: @Peter thank you but, I want to ask why? Because,  $a \mod b= c$. If and only if $b>c$. Isn't it? Really I can not understand the concept.

Comment: Polynomial division is analogue to division in positive integers, but it is nevertheless not the same. Given $f(x),g(x)$ , there are unique polynomials $u(x),v(x)$ with deg(v)<deg(g) and $f(x)=g(x)\cdot u(x)+v(x)$. Since $g(x)\cdot u(x)$ need not be non-negative we can have $f(x)<v(x)$ (for some or for all $x$)

Comment: @Peter thank you for explanation.

Comment: The first notation is the most mathematical. The second notation looks like Mathematica code.

Comment: What about   $a \equiv a \mod (b)$ ?